# Как в тестах с enzyme узнать количество tr в table?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs, enzyme

```js
it('test for check DOM', () => {
  const props = {
    initialHeight: 4,
    initialWidth: 4
  };
  const newContainer = mount(<Squares {...props} />);

  expect(newContainer.find('table').find('tr')).to.have.length(4);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
expect(newContainer.find('tbody').find('tr').first().children().length).toEqual(props.initialHeight - 1);
```